# Which browsers have problems caching XMLHTTPRequest responses?

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, xmlhttprequest, cross-browser

Do any of the currently popular browsers have particular problems caching* XMLHttpRequest responses that I need to be aware of?

I'd like to be able to include XMLHttpRequest queries on every page as a method of dynamically loading content (ie JSON) or behaviour (like eval()ed Javascript) relevant to the type of page, but wanted to make sure that the resources it receives from the server could be cached, if the server sent the right headers.

I was concerned to read [this article which mentions](http://www.subbu.org/blog/2005/10/xmlhttprequest-and-caching) that browsers such as Firefox 1.1 do not cache any content obtained via XMLHTTPRequest, and that it always requests new data is sent completely (with Cache-Control and no If-Modified-Since) regardless of headers sent by the server.

Obviously that article is very old - I don't even remember a Firefox 1.1; so what are the considerations I need to make for current popular browsers and is there any trick for when I specifically *want* responses to be cached?

**To clarify my question, by caching, I mean client-side caching, where the server issues freshness information (in the form of a Cache-Control: max-age directive or an Expires: header) and the browser stores a copy of the response in its cache along with an expiry date, so that future requests for the same resource issued from subsequent pages can be satisfied from the browser cache without the need for any contact with the server at all.  All major browsers do this correctly for most content, but I've heard that Firefox cannot do this for XMLHttpRequest content.  What I'm asking is if anyone knows of cases where any of the modern browsers do not cache responses according to the spec when using XMLHttpRequest.*

Comment: it's better, and more consistent to control it in you JS.  if you don't need to refresh, don't query.

Comment: How do you mean?  Could you give an example?  I'd like to be able to fetch something from the server, but if the browser has it in its cache from a previous page and it's not expired, for that to prevent it from cause a server trip.  I still want the data though, I can't just not query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mark Nottingham has [an excellent set of functional tests](http://www.mnot.net/javascript/xmlhttprequest/cache.html) that demonstrate browser XMLHttpRequest caching behaviour. Load up the page in the browsers you want to support and work out what techniques you can and cannot rely on to have your response cached.

Comment: Thanks very much for that.  It's looking quite promising, as Firefox did pass those 'freshness' tests (including all the ones with 'Expire').

Comment: the script does not appear to work anymore. tested in Chrome. lots on security warnings in console

Answer (score 4):

Although some browsers have different defaults (by default, IE will cache results from AJAX requests, but Firefox, by default, will not), all browsers that I'm aware of will obey the http headers, such as [Cache-Control](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL). So just set the caching headers correctly for your application.

Here is an example:

```
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        var model = [...];
        Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        return Json(model);
    }
```

Now IE and Firefox will both behave the same; they will never cache the results of the action.

Comment: i wouldn't be so sure.  IE6's cache is too aggressive.  i've been bitten several times by it.  if you don't want queries to be cached, add arandom postfix to the URL (an unused parameter is ok)

Comment: Unfortunately this is the opposite of what I need - I'd like to make sure the response _is_ cached.  That is, if the browser can satisfy the request with a previous response from its cache that hasn't expired, I'd like it to do so and prevent and need to make a request to the origin server at all.

Comment: Javier, that will work, but it delegates cache policy to the client, which is IMHO the wrong place for it.

Comment: thomas, I understand your needs, but I can't set policy for you. Do read the link I included. Look at the public and max-age values.

Comment: Sorry, I probably haven't made myself clear enough.  I am fully aware of the HTTP specification including all the ways for the server to specify freshness information. However, not all browsers obey all of it, and I wanted to know if there were any that had problems specifically with XMLHTTPRequest.