# JQuery AJAX Not executing on random occasions

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using JQuery's AJAX to send values to my PHP server to interpret and handle these values.

Currently, everything works fine, except on random occasions (every once-in-a-while) it just does not seem to complete/execute the AJAX correctly.

This is the code I use to AJAX with:

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'setting.php?a=<?php echo $companyid; ?>',
        dataType : 'text',
        data:{old : $old_, newer : $newer_, action : $act_},
        success : function(data)
            {
                     if (data.error === true)
                     {
                       alert("An error has occured, the page will refresh itself.");
                       location.reload();
                     }
                     alert('SET');
            },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                     alert("An error has occured, the page will refresh itself.");
                     location.reload();
            }
    });
```

Every time the AJAX completes, a message pops up with the text `SET` and I can view the results in a text file created by the PHP file/code. (It writes the values received into a text file for testing purposes)

So every now and then it just doesn't alert me with `SET` and the text file remains the same as was before that try.

What can I possibly do about this glitch?

Thanks!

Comment: If I were you I'd add some id to the POSTed data and print that out on both the client before you submit, and on the server side. Comparing these logs will show if you are POSTing data when you think you are. Could be simply that your ajax submission *isn't* happening.

Comment: I am 100% sure that the data is what I think it is, its a simple form with a few inputs, and that values gets sent, also fwrite'ed to file. So I can see it is what I just typed. (If that is what you meant?)

Comment: Any JS errors showing in whatever browser you are using? Firefox and Chrome are good for error reporting.

Comment: Ah, good idea! Will check that quickly

Comment: Out of interest, what are $old_, $newer_ and $act_? If they are PHP strings then they need to be quoted correctly in the `data` object. Or if they are jQuerified values then they also may not work as expected as properties of `data`.

Comment: Ok, I used Chrome's `Developer Tools` and when the problem occurred, nothing got printed in the `Console` or at `Scripts` :(

Comment: Could caching this be an issue? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677480/which-browsers-have-problems-caching-xmlhttprequest-responses

Comment: These values are JQuery strings for example `$old_ = 'Hello';` Will try that caching thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use FireFox, get FireBug and check the response, and posted request.

Other than that, I Would do some alerts in your javascript to make sure it's working every time.

When does the AJAX request occur? During a click, on a timer???? My guess is it has something to do with that. Or it's waiting for a response, and you're submitting the request again.

Comment: If you read the question, I do use alerts. It does initiate. But every once in a while it does not complete/end the request. This without any errors. Every other time the request works 100% fine.

Comment: Good point. But I meant adding alerts to make sure even the AJAX function is being called to try to get to the root of the problem. Firebug is a good plugin for FireFox that will tell you what's going on. You can see every post from the console and see if the .ajax is even firing. At this point, you don't know where the problem is, so you need to step through to find out. That will help.